# Cable to record from iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, recording

I want to play audio from an iPhone and record it on a Mac or PC. Can a simple male to male stereo cable be used as headphones to the iPhone and a recording device to a PC or Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but before connecting it together.

1. Set the iPhone Volume to be about 80%.

This is a approximation of the audio line input levels that the Mac audio jack (when in input mode will expect), don't go higher as this possible might damage the port, or distort.  Much lower that 80% may mean more noise on the recording.

Then

2. Use shortcut to use Audio Port for Input

Hold Option (aka Alt) and then click on the audio icon on the system bar menu tool bar.  Under "Use Audio Port For:" Click on Input, see image:

[image]

This is much faster when switching back and forwards, please note if you use the single jack for headphones too the next time you plug them in, the sound will still be going out the internal speakers until you change the port over to Output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's nothing why it shouldn't work.

Please not that some Macs only have one headphone Jack. Even if it automatically switches to in&output when you plug in an (Apple) Headset, you'll have to set it manually to input when using a normal male-male cable.

To do this, open Settings>Audio and you'll find a dropdown box. ('use headphone jack as...' or so)